# How to Convert following code (foreach and if) into linq in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How to Convert the below for each to Linq and if possible include the If statement into the Linq also.?

```
public class InvalidDataType
    {
        public string ViewName { get; set; }
        public string ControlName { get; set; }
        public string DataValue { get; set; }
    }

foreach (InvalidDataType invalidField in DataObjectManager.GetInvalidFields())
           {
                if (invalidField.ControlName == "tbMCBNumber")
                {
                    fieldToRemove = invalidField;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (fieldToRemove != null)
            {
                DataObjectManager.GetInvalidFields().Remove(fieldToRemove);
            }
```

This is the code I tried

```
DataObjectManager.GetInvalidFields().Where(x => x.ControlName == "tbMCBNumber").Remove();
```

Comment: This isn't a code writing service I'm afraid. You need to demonstrate some effort and show us what you have tried.

Comment: Why not do it yourself? Why should we do your job? This is trying and thinking. When you have a *specific* problem you may ask here.

Comment: Also, what makes you think Linq would be a good solution here?

Answer (score 0):

`Where` just returns a **new** collection, it doesn´t modifiy the **existing** one. That´s what the Q in LINQ stands for: **query**. This means linq isnt designed and therefor not really good when modifying collections. This is whyt you shouldn´t use LINQ when modifying the elements within your collections.

If your `GetInvalidFields`-methods returns a `List<T>` you can do the following:

```
DataObjectManager.GetInvalidFields().RemoveAll(x => x.ControlName == "tbMCBNumber");
```

This however isn´t LINQ, it´s just a method for `ICollection<T>`, which `List<T>` implements.

Alternativly you could use a single for-loop that couints backwards in order to remove some items from it:

```
var list = DataObjectManager.GetInvalidFields();
for(int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if(list[i].ControlName == "tbMCBNumber").Remove(list[i]);
}
```

However this assumes you even can modify the *underlying* collection that `GetInvalidFields` returns. If that method returns something that can´t be modified at all like a `ReadOnlyCollection` or just en iterator there´s no way to remove items from that.